# How to make the "ylim" of two plots to be exactly the same in R

Tags: r, plot

## Background

I have a function called `TPN`. When you run this function, it produces two plots (**see picture below**). The bottom-row plot samples from the top-row plot.

## Question

I'm wondering how I could **fix** the `ylim` of **the bottom-row plot** to be always (i.e., regardless of the input values) **the same** as `ylim` of the **top-row plot?**

## R code is provided below the picture (Run the entire block of code).

[image]

```
############## Input Values #################
TPN = function(          each.sub.pop.n = 150, 
                         sub.pop.means = 20:10, 
                         predict.range = 10:0, 
                         sub.pop.sd = .75,
                         n.sample = 2   ) {
#############################################
par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )

m = matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ); layout(m)
set.seed(2460986)
Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )
set.seed(NULL)
x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)

plot(x, y) ## Plot #1


sample <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, replace = TRUE))
sample <- data.frame(y = unlist(sample), 
                 x = as.numeric(rep(names(sample), each = n.sample)))

plot(sample$x, sample$y) ## Plot # 2

 }
 ## TEST HERE:
TPN()
```

Comment: You have to do this explicitly. Combine y and sample$y, `myRange <- range(c(y, sample$y))`. Then use myRange as the argument to ylim. You could get a bit fancier by calculating the floor-1 and ceiling+1 of the combined vector or something like that.

Comment: If you had done this in either lattice with panels or in ggplot2 with facets the default settings would have given identical ylims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `ylim` using `par("yaxp")[1:2]`. So, you can change the second plot code to have its `ylim` as the first plot's:

```
plot(sample$x, sample$y, ylim = par("yaxp")[1:2]) ## Plot # 2
```

or as mentioned in the comments, you can simply set the `ylim` for both plots to be range of both data-sets and add that to **both** plots:

```
ylim = range(c(y, sample$y))
```

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi I've seen your comment/answer and agree with you on that. I prefer to have it as a general solution which can be applied to here and maybe later for a similar problem. But you're correct. Here, `sample` is a subset of the dataset and its range won't be larger than the one of the original dataset.

Comment: @user138773 Just rearrange the code and have your plot lines at the end of it. Not just because of this issue, but as a general practice, plotting should come in the last steps; this will let you to apply whatever you want on your data-frames and at the end those changes will appear in your plots. But if there's a reason that you prefer to keep your code as is and don't want the first solution that I proposed, then 李哲源ZheyuanLi's answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Produce the same plot again but with `type = "n"` and then filling the points with `points()`. For example, change your plot 2 to

```
plot(x, y, type = "n")
points(sample$x, sample$y)
```

A benefit of this approach is that everything in the plot will be exactly the same, not just the y-axis (which may or may not matter for your function).